# what is mapping in sql?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

how to map tables in sql?

i have three tables . i want  to map this tables using sql queries.

student 'table1'

```
Studnt_id   password
123         5525
124         2233
```

student_info 'table 2'

```
Studnt_id   student_name    subject marks
123              gautam     maths     90
124              gaurav     maths     85
```

student_personal_info  'table 3'

```
firstname   lastname    address
gautam      jethva          banglore, karnataka
gaurav      rathod          jamnagar , gujarat
```

i want to map this three table and show in the result id, student_name , lastname,subject, marks, address

Answer (score 0):

You need to [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) (map) tables together; Jeff Atwood has a great overview of how these work in his article, "[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)"

In your example above, you should be able to use the studn_id column to link the tables `student` ('table1') and  `student_info` ('table2') together.  The third may be trickier as it doesn't appear to have a guaranteed key back to either of the first two tables.

Example:

```
SELECT S.student_name, S.subject, S.marks 
FROM student S
INNER JOIN student_info SI ON S.Studnt_id = SI.Studnt_id
```

Will give you all the rows in `student` that have a matching row in `student_info`

However, linking the third table, `student_personal_info` is much harder. Your issue here is that there doesn't seem to be a unique way of pulling in the rows in this table for a specific student - you could try joining on name, but this isn't guaranteed to be unique.

The table student_personal_info really should have the column `Studnt_id` in it to make unique selection of rows for a specific student possible. Given your specific example, however, the following will work:

```
SELECT S.student_name, S.subject, S.marks, SPI.lastname, SPI.address 
FROM student S
INNER JOIN student_info SI ON S.Studnt_id = SI.Studnt_id
INNER JOIN student_personal_info SPI ON SI.student_name = SPI.firstname
```

However, if more than one student shares the same first name, you'll get multiple matches.

Comment: thanks for the immediate reply......yes you are right about SPI ..........THANKS AGAIN